# Displaying an array from xml resources in ListView not working

Tags: android, xml, arrays, android-listview

I have an array in my resources that I want to display in a `ListView` but I'm failing miserably so maybe someone can tell what I'm doing wrong and what should I do to accomplish this. Here is the code I' using:

In my XML resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">myApp</string>
<string-array name="EstadosArray">
    <item >Estado1</item>
    <item >Estado2</item>
    <item >Estado3</item>
    <item >Estado4</item>
    <item >Estado5</item>
    <item >Estado6</item>        
</string-array>
</resources>
```

In my Activity:

```
public class myMain extends Activity{
String[] Estados;
eAdapter ea=null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Estados = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.EstadosArray);
    ea = new eAdapter();
    ListView EstadosList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.estadosList);
    EstadosList.setAdapter(ea);

}

class eAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    eAdapter() {
            super(myMain.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Estados);
            }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        eHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.esatdoitem, null);
            holder = new eHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (eHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(Estados.get(position));  // HERE IS WHERE I HAVE THE issue is, I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET THE POSITION, IS GIVING ME AN ERROR (CANNOT INVOKE GET(INT) ON THE ARRAY TYPE STRING[])
        return (convertView);
    }

}
class eHolder{
    public TextView esname=null;
    eHolder(View row) {
        esname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ename);
    }
    void populateFrom(String est) {
        esname.setText(est);
    }
}
```

I know that the issue is because string[] is not int but how can I fix that? That's how I will fill every row of my list.

Edit: `LogCat` added:

```
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.zvzej.jlgproapps.mexicoguia.myMain$eHolder.populateFrom(myMain.java:468)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.zvzej.jlgproapps.mexicoguia.myMain$eAdapter.getView(myMain.java:456)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 17:09:46.290: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a `caused by` line or two not included here in your logcat?

Comment: I included the complete logcat that eclipse show me.

Comment: when I hover over the log cat, where my package name is it gives me line 456 and line 467, thats where the populate call and form are.

Comment: plus this on top of the log cat 05-03 17:39:00.126: W/dalvikvm(320): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-03 17:39:00.146: E/AndroidRuntime(320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 17:39:00.146: E/AndroidRuntime(320): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you post your `esatdoitem` layout?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: my bad I see the problem I actually wrote the wrong name for the item xml!

Comment: Glad you found the answer and thanks for the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
holder.populateFrom(Estados[position]);
```

**Addition**

Is this:

```
    esname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ename);
```

Supposed to be:

```
    esname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.esname);
```

Comment: @ Sam, thanks for helping, now is not giving me the error in the main Activity, but when I run it it crashes right in that line.

Comment: What is the logcat? Please include relevant code from your eHolder class if necessary.

Comment: eholder is just like I posted in the original post and I just added the log cat

Comment: Ha, I didn't see it there! Do you have plans to make this more complex? Otherwise I could suggest an approach using built-in methods. Give me a moment on the errors.

Comment: No this list is just going to contain 32 items fix, because those states or estados will never change.

Comment: Nop my problem was on the item list name of the xml file. Thanks